# Sorting rows with merged cells

Tags: excel, vba, merge

Usually I avoid using merged cells but we got sheets from management software having something like this:

[image: example]

I found the easiest process is to un-merge, sort, then merge again but with a `header` to the table and the `sheet number of sheets` it became tedious. The fused cells are known (I+J, M+N) and table starts at row 11 so the page is set.

I tweaked a code which does the unmerge then merge part but need to make it sort, and is there a cleaner code than this

```
Sub Merge_fused()
    '~~> unmerged range
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("H11:X56")
    '~~> merged columns
    Dim IRange As Range
    Set IRange = Range("I11:J56")
    Dim MRange As Range
    Set MRange = Range("M11:N56")
    Dim VRange As Range
    Set VRange = Range("V11:W56")

    On Error Resume Next

    With MyRange
        .UnMerge
    End With

    '~~> i need to sort MyRange here

    With IRange
        .Merge True
    End With

    With MRange
        .Merge True
    End With

    With VRange
        .Merge True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Start by using the macro recorder in Excel.

Comment: i tried it but seems the process is a bit complex for it, since when ran it empty the page

Comment: `EDIT: i found this which do the unmerge sort part`: What did you find?

Comment: forgot the code, fixed now

Comment: well i have to return them to their first stat with sorting, sadly its not my choice

Comment: if it wouldn't be a bother, can you post a screen shot of how it will look like after the process of sorting? or are those just numbers with `,` as default separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a bit older but I just came across this and made the code work for me.
I add this code where it says `'~~> i need to sort here the MyRange here`

```
projp.Range("your range").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlNo
```

Works perfectly for me

Answer (score 0):

I'd do an automatic unmerge, and then just throw away the empty cells that pop up.  So: no re-merging afterwards.  This way you can afterwards sort your data anyway and anytime you want.  The following code does just that (it also inserts blank cells at the end of the data table in case anything is following the table to the right).

```
' Unmerges the given column over the given rows
Sub UnmergeDataColumn( _
  theSheet As Worksheet, _
  firstCell As Range, lastCell As Range, _
  columnNrAfterTable As Long, _
  startMergedColumn As String, endMergedColumn As String _
)
  ' Unmerge the merged columns
  Dim mergedColumns As Range
  Set mergedColumns = theSheet.Range( _
    startMergedColumn & firstCell.Row, _
    endMergedColumn & lastCell.Row _
  )
  Call mergedColumns.UnMerge

  ' Throw away all unneeded cells
  Dim emptyColumn As Range
  Set emptyColumn = theSheet.Range( _
    endMergedColumn & firstCell.Row, _
    endMergedColumn & lastCell.Row _
  )
  Call emptyColumn.Delete(xlShiftToLeft)

  ' And insert extra padding after the table
  Dim trailingColumn As Range
  Set trailingColumn = theSheet.Range( _
    theSheet.Cells(firstCell.Row, columnNrAfterTable), _
    theSheet.Cells(lastCell.Row, columnNrAfterTable) _
  )
  Call trailingColumn.Insert(xlShiftToRight)
End Sub

Sub UnmergeData()
  ' Get the sheet
  Dim theSheet As Worksheet
  Set theSheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")

  ' Get the range of our table
  Dim firstCell As Range
  Set firstCell = theSheet.Range("K11")
  Dim lastCell As Range
  Set lastCell = theSheet.Range("X11").End(xlDown)
  Dim columnNrAfterTable As Long
  columnNrAfterTable = lastCell.Offset(0, 1).Column

  ' And unmerge the columns
  Call UnmergeDataColumn( _
    theSheet, _
    firstCell, lastCell, _
    columnNrAfterTable, _
    "V", "W" _
  )
  Call UnmergeDataColumn( _
    theSheet, _
    firstCell, lastCell, _
    columnNrAfterTable, _
    "M", "N" _
  )
  Call UnmergeDataColumn( _
    theSheet, _
    firstCell, lastCell, _
    columnNrAfterTable, _
    "I", "J" _
  )
End Sub
```